# What and when clears content of /data/local/tmp?

Tags: shell

I plan to copy and start precompiled binary from  /data/local/tmp and I would like to get any information one edge cases that might cause some potential issue, like - what and when this folder being cleared out during either normal OS operation or reboot? Okay, the reboot case is obvious but what about normal operation? Do these "Clear cache" tools normally clear it out as well? Any default services/daemons that do that?

Comment: I beg to differ that a reboot deletes files in /data/local/tmp. Never did a reboot delete any of my files located there in any of my phone.

Comment: it is never cleared

Comment: ... at least on stock Android.